# How to get the right answer form in axios

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I use axios, the answer to my query comes in the form of `response.data.response.object`. How can I get an answer without `response.data` immediately `response.object`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's work

```
export function name(param) {
return axios.get(`URL`,
    {transformResponse: axios.defaults.transformResponse.concat((response) => {
            return response.response
        })
    }
)}
```

Comment: Concatenating seems a good solution whenever you want to customly transform object instead of a string. This `axios.default.transformResponse` method already performs JSON.parse for you (https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/b4c5d35d2875191dfa8c3919d4227dce8e2ad23f/lib/defaults.js#L58-L66), so you can be sure that next transformResponse function in chain (custom one) will be passed result of JSON.parse

Answer (score 2):

You cannot achieve what you want like that, axios returns the body of the response from within the data object.

Although, you can do this:

```
let response = response.data.response;
```

And then you can use `response.object`

EDIT: As stated in the other answer, this is definitely doable, although I would advise against manipulating the structure in which axios sends its response as this makes assumptions about the structure of the JSON response. (especially if being setup as a global setting)

Comment: Seriously? Just save to variable? The question was about setting up axios

Comment: While it's possible to manipulate the structure that axios sends its response in I wouldn't advise it, it's very inflexible and makes assumptions about the returned result which could easily create issues. Especially if this is applied as a global setting and not all of your endpoints return data in that specific format.

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.defaults.transformResponse = [function (data) {
    // Do whatever you want to transform the data

    return JSON.parse(data).response.object;
  }],
```

then now you can access to your object by just typing: response.data